# Generating Header Files from Object Files

Tags: c, code-generation

Is it possible to take an object file (like a macintosh dylib or a linux .so file), and automatically generate a C .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The object file basically contains a mapping (that you can display with a command such as `nm`) from symbol names to addresses, but there is absolutely no type information.

I'm simplifying a bit (some symbols are used but not defined in the object file, others are defined there), but the answer is still no.

As an example, here is the result of `nm a.out` on whatever random file I last compiled :)
The example is so small that the gcc builtins outnumber the symbols I defined myself. But no type information...

```
$ nm a.out 
0000200c D _NXArgc
00002008 D _NXArgv
00002000 D ___progname
00001fbc t __dyld_func_lookup
00001000 A __mh_execute_header
00002004 D _environ
         U _exit
00001fca T _main
         U _rand
00002030 S _x
00002010 d dyld__mach_header
00001fa8 t dyld_stub_binding_helper
00001f68 T start
```

Comment: This is not true if it is compiled with debugging symbols.  libbfd may be able to read it, or you may be able to get a library for whatever debugging format you're using.

Comment: @Tim But the arguments to functions would still be a mystery to you.